# why does count function return one row?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I have query like this using PDO

```
"SELECT category.id AS id, category.static_name AS   static_name,   category.name AS name, COUNT(training.id) AS trainings_count
        FROM category
        JOIN training   ON training.cat_id = category.id"
```

When all columns are empty, the count function returns one row and the whole function return true. So what is the solution for this problem ?

Comment: BEcause you don't have `group by` add a `group by category.id` at the end

Comment: `COUNT(training.id)` will at least return one row containing "0".

Comment: Thanks, works . Small changs always make big different xD

Answer (score 0):

If you don't group the answers by some category, it will count everything that is returned and give you one answer.  This is the way that all aggregate functions (count, sum, min, max, etc.) are supposed to function.

So the question is, what do you want a count of.  Add a clause `group by <blah>` where `<blah>` is the item that you are wanting to count the items of.